# ApplySymbologyFromLayer does not work in my python code

Tags: arcpy, symbology, .net

I have  a layer file. I make a button in ArcGIS 10 with .NET. I want to change layer symbology with the layer file. For this purpose, I write python code and execute it from C#. If the following code is written in python window of ArcGIS, then works fantastic. But from my code, it does not work. Can anyone help me?

```
try
           {
               const string prg = @"import sys
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT')
layer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[0]
    arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(layer,'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\Junctions_Temp.lyr')
"
               ;
           var sw = new StreamWriter("D:\\test2.py");
           sw.Write(prg); // write this program to a file
           sw.Close();
           var p = new Process
                       {
                           StartInfo =
                               {
                                   FileName = @"C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\python.exe",
                                   RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                                   UseShellExecute = false,
                                   Arguments = "D:\\test2.py "
                               }
                       }; // create process (i.e., the python program
           p.Start();
```

Comment: have you tried with "refresh" arcpy.RefreshTOC()
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

Comment: @radouxju: Thanks for ur reply.I have already tried with your code arcpy.RefreshTOC() arcpy.RefreshActiveView() , but no result.